# Fix Git UU with VI

Tags: git, kdiff3

When I pull the code from remote, the git reports conflicts on one file.

UU hello.cpp

If I use `git mergetool hello.cpp` and fix the conflict, then git shows the following: The default mergetool is kdiff3.

```
M  hello.cpp
```

However, if I use vi to fix the conflicts, git stills show the following

```
UU hello.cpp
```

I have to use `git add hello.cpp` in order to show the following

```
M hello.cpp
```

What does kdiff3 do after finishing the merge so that git will show `M` instead of `UU` if I do it with vi?

Answer (score 2):

kdiff3 does a 'git add' when done. You can (and did) do the same thing using vi to fix the conflicts and the command line.  See 'git help merge'  "How to Resolve Conflicts"